# SORT QUERY Too Slow in Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a simple dataset with following node structure
id : int, txt : string

and have 400 000 nodes and I have created an index on id property.
When I am running simple query

```
profile MATCH (n:LABEL) RETURN n.id LIMIT 25
```

This is using index and running fast but when I am running this query

```
profile MATCH (n:LABEL) RETURN n.id order by n.id desc limit 25
```

This query is not using index and returning result in around 1200ms on every time basis.

What am I missing and why the indexes are not getting used in this query?

Answer (score 1):

This is an achilles heel of Neo4j, as [ORDER BY indexed properties still doesn't utilize the indexes](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6584).

APOC Procedures has some support for obtaining an [ordered range utilizing the index](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_schema_index_queries), though I've encountered some issues with that previously. Haven't rechecked functionality lately, so it may be worth trying it out.